# Editing a Sub within another Sub

Tags: vba, excel

Having trouble figuring out how to edit a sub from within another sub. I tried this:

```
Sub Sub1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Useless"
End Sub

Sub Sub2()
    Dim test as string
    test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

    If test = "here" Then
        Call Sub1 
        With Sub1 
           ws.Range("A2").Value = test.Value
        End With
    End If
```

I get an `expected function or variable` error back, probably due to the fact that `Sub1` should be a function. But even once that's changed to a function, `Sub2` still doesn't work correctly though the code runs.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the With-Statement is for.

Comment: @Frame probably the cause of the issue, and my misunderstanding of `With`. My goal was to use `Sub1`, hoping`with` would give me the ability to use any defined variables from `Sub1`

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track actually when you tried converting `Sub1` to a function. You just need to make the function "return" the created worksheet object. Here:

```
Function Sub1() As Worksheet     ' Don't forget to use a different name for Sub1 (and
'                                  preferably Sub2 as well).
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Useless"

    Set Sub1 = ws
End Function

Sub Sub2()
    Dim test As String
    test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

    If test = "here" Then
        With Sub1
           .Range("A2").Value = test
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously, you would need to change the name of `Sub1` to something else that reflects what the function does.

Also, notice that I used `test` instead of your `test.Value` because `test` is a string already and doesn't have a `Value` property.

Comment: Beat me to it. Was just writing up an example Function returning a Workbook. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public ws As Worksheet

Sub Sub1()

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ws.Range("A1") = "Useless"

End Sub

Sub Sub2()

    Dim test As String        
    test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
    If test = "here" Then
        Sub1
        ws.Range("A2") = test
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question on this, is there a way for VBA to already acknowledge the defined variables from Sub1 so there's no need to redefine in Sub2?

Comment: @S31 - public variables.

Comment: Are there drawbacks to using public variables? I have a code at hand that has quite a few subs with repeated variable names and I'm concerned another sub might use the public variables in case `Sub1` is called anywhere else

Comment: @S31 = drawbacks for using public variables - the code is considered really bad, senior developers can tell you, you are polluting the scope, managers would scream at you for being low-quality dev. 
But if you can manage them, it is ok. :D

Comment: awesome, sounds great

Comment: Having personally had the joy of working on a multi-module project with hundreds of global variables, some of them shadowed by procedure-scope variables, and their intent being everything but clear: I'd advise against using them whenever possible. I do use them in my own projects, but sparingly. (And I guess, that's what @Vityata said?)

Comment: @Inarion - the good thing about VBA is that the big projects are maximum up to 2-3 developers. Thus, you may consider "polluting" the scope in some cases. It is up to you. But in general a senior or a manager seeing them would scream as an Italian chef being asked for a Ketchup on the pizza. :)

Comment: There may be only 2-3 (or more likely just one, in our case) devs working *in parallel*, but given the age of some software projects in corporate environments, there are some more devs involved *in sequence*. (And there is not enough time to refactor the whole thing.)

Comment: @Inarion - not enough time to refactor, because the documentation does not exist. And the "old" devs love saying - "the code is the best documentation"... And then you see managers who believe this... I guess this is happening only with VBA, in the other world it would never happen.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by passing the variable as an argument:

```
Sub Sub1(ByRef ws As Worksheet)  'The variable is passed ByRef as default, but wanted to make it clear.

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ws.Range("A1") = "Useless" 'Value is the default property of Range.

End Sub

Sub Sub2()

    Dim test As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")

    If test = "here" Then
        Sub1 wrkSht 'Pass the variable to Sub1 to get defined.
        wrkSht.Range("A2") = test
    End If
End Sub
```

Or turn `Sub1` into a function that returns a reference to the worksheet:

```
Function Sub1() As Worksheet
    Set Sub1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
End Function

Sub Sub2()
    Dim test As String
    test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")

    If test = "here" Then
        Sub1.Range("A2") = test
    End If
End Sub
```